# Probability & statistics

Tags: probability

In each of two closets there are three cartons. Five of the cartons con-
tain canned vegetables. The other carton contains canned fruits: ten
cans of pears, eight cans of peaches, and six cans of fruit cocktail. Each
can of fruit cocktail contains 300 chunks of fruit of approximately
equal size, of which three are cherries. If a child goes into one of the
closets, unpacks one of the cartons, opens a can and eats two pieces of
its contents, what is the probability that two cherries will be eaten?

Comment: Have you tried making yourself a tree-diagram?  This should be a straightforward application of multiplication principle of probability.  To have eaten two cherries, first the child must have picked the correct closet.  Then he must have picked a fruit carton, not one of the vegetable cartons.  Next, the child must have picked a can of fruit cocktail from the carton, not a pear or peach can.  Then, the child must have picked a cherry, not one of the other fruits from the can.  Finally, the child must have picked a cherry again, not one of the other fruits from the can.

Comment: will it be (1/2)*(1/3)*(6/24)*(3/300)*(2/299)

Comment: Yes.  In the future, include any thoughts and attempts you have in the post itself.  People often do not respond well to posts which are *just* questions and no other context.

Comment: aha .... thanks for the suggestion...actually I wanted to verify my answer. I will keep your suggestion in future for sure